# Dynamically update DataGridComboBoxColumn (not MVVM)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid that its source is DB based. the code is not in MVVM.

Now, i need the DataGridComboBoxColumn source to changed based on a different DataGridComboBoxColumn value thats in the same DataGrid- I'm sure there is a simple solution, but still, couldnt figure it out- how do i do that?

My code:

XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="active_idnt_deviceCmb"  SelectedValueBinding="{Binding idnt_linked_io_device}" DisplayMemberPath="correct_idnt_active_logic_device" SelectedValuePath="idnt_active_device" Header="input id" Width="80"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="active_device_addressCmb" ElementStyle="{StaticResource MyComboBoxStyle}"  SelectedValueBinding="{Binding idnt_linked_io_device}" DisplayMemberPath="active_device_address" SelectedValuePath="active_device_address" Header="Relay Address" Width="65"><DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="changeDeviceAddress" />
            </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

cs:

```
private void changeDeviceAddress(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    HelpDataSet.ACTIVE_IO_DEVICESDataTable dtActiveIo = new HelpDataSet.ACTIVE_IO_DEVICESDataTable();
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

    if (comboBox.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        AppHelp.ActiveIODeviceAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
        AppHelp.ActiveIODeviceAdapter.FillByIdntRelayAddress(dtActiveIo, comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
        active_idnt_deviceCmb.ItemsSource = dtActiveIo.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

but it changes the whole column source and not just of the specific cell in the row.

Comment: Delete all that and use proper DataBinding.

Comment: @HighCore How do i do it?

Comment: You may be interested to read the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx)  It will explain how to use your `DataContext` to your advantage.

Comment: @DasDas Can you please explain why do you have DataGridComboBoxColumn inside anothere DataGridComboBoxColumn? Do you want to change the source of active_device_addressCmb whe the active_idnt_deviceCmb was changed?

Comment: @Ilan i want to change the source of active_idnt_deviceCmb when the active_device_addressCmb was changed

Comment: @DasDas Why do you have DataGridComboBoxColumn tag inside anothere DataGridComboBoxColumn tag?

Comment: @Ilan it was a mistake- i edited it

Answer (score 2):

here is solution which doesn't use the MVVM approach at all, it based on the WPF selection oriented behavior. Please keep in mind that all models just presents a data grid rows, they does'n have any additional functionality. The Source collection collecting is triggered in the behavior by a combo selection trigger. 
Here is the code:
 1. XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboWithoutCodeBehind.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:comboWithoutCodeBehind="clr-namespace:ComboWithoutCodeBehind"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="This">
    <Grid >
        <DataGrid x:Name="SelectDataGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Persons}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dgCheckBox" Header="Select" Width="45" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="FIRST NAME" Width="125" Binding="{Binding FNAME}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="LAST NAME" Width="125" Binding="{Binding LNAME}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selection" Width="120">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ComboBox Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="DataGridTemplateColumnComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=ServersCollection}" 
                                      DisplayMemberPath="ServerName"></ComboBox>
                                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="DbName">
                                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <comboWithoutCodeBehind:ItemsSourcePosessingBehavior 
                                        SourceProvidingFactory="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=MainSourceProvidingFactory}"
                                            SiblingComboBox="{Binding ElementName=DataGridTemplateColumnComboBox}"/>
                                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

2. Code behind, models and factory code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Persons",
        typeof (ObservableCollection<Person>), typeof (MainWindow),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<Person>)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MainSourceProvidingFactoryProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MainSourceProvidingFactory", typeof (SourceProvidingFactory),
            typeof (MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(SourceProvidingFactory)));

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Person>)GetValue(PersonsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PersonsProperty, value); }
    }

    public SourceProvidingFactory MainSourceProvidingFactory
    {
        get { return (SourceProvidingFactory)GetValue(MainSourceProvidingFactoryProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainSourceProvidingFactoryProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        MainSourceProvidingFactory = new SourceProvidingFactory(GetCollection);
        InitSources();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DbDetails> GetCollection(object arg)
    {
        //you can perform your db relate logic here
        var sereverDetails = arg as ServerDetails;
        return sereverDetails == null ? null : new ObservableCollection<DbDetails>(sereverDetails.DbDetailses);
    }


    private void InitSources()
    {
        var l = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person {FNAME = "John", LNAME = "W"},
            new Person {FNAME = "George", LNAME = "R"},
            new Person {FNAME = "Jimmy", LNAME = "B"},
            new Person {FNAME = "Marry", LNAME = "B"},
            new Person {FNAME = "Ayalot", LNAME = "A"},
        };
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>(l);

        ServersCollection = new ObservableCollection<ServerDetails>(new List<ServerDetails>
        {
            new ServerDetails
            {
                ServerName = "A",
                DbDetailses = new List<DbDetails>
                {
                    new DbDetails {DbName = "AA"},
                    new DbDetails {DbName = "AB"},
                    new DbDetails {DbName = "AC"},
                }
            },
            new ServerDetails
            {
                ServerName = "B",
                DbDetailses = new List<DbDetails>
                {
                    new DbDetails {DbName = "BA"},
                    new DbDetails {DbName = "BB"},
                    new DbDetails {DbName = "BC"},
                }
            },
            new ServerDetails
            {
                ServerName = "C",
                DbDetailses = new List<DbDetails>
                {
                    new DbDetails {DbName = "CA"},
                    new DbDetails {DbName = "CB"},
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public ObservableCollection<ServerDetails> ServersCollection { get; set; }
}

public class SourceProvidingFactory
{
    public SourceProvidingFactory(Func<object, ObservableCollection<DbDetails>> action)
    {
        GetCollection = action;
    }

    public Func<object, ObservableCollection<DbDetails>> GetCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Person : BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _lName;
    private string _fName;
    private bool _checked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _checked; }
        set
        {
            _checked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string LNAME
    {
        get { return _lName; }
        set
        {
            _lName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string FNAME
    {
        get { return _fName; }
        set
        {
            _fName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class ServerDetails : BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _serverName;

    public string ServerName
    {
        get { return _serverName; }
        set
        {
            _serverName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<DbDetails> DbDetailses { get; set; }
}

public class DbDetails : BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _dbName;

    public string DbName
    {
        get { return _dbName; }
        set
        {
            _dbName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

3. Behavior code:

```
public class ItemsSourcePosessingBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox>
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SiblingComboBoxProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SiblingComboBox", typeof(ComboBox), typeof(ItemsSourcePosessingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(ComboBox)));

    public ComboBox SiblingComboBox
    {
        get { return (ComboBox)GetValue(SiblingComboBoxProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SiblingComboBoxProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProvidingFactoryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SourceProvidingFactory", typeof (SourceProvidingFactory), typeof (ItemsSourcePosessingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(SourceProvidingFactory)));

    public SourceProvidingFactory SourceProvidingFactory
    {
        get { return (SourceProvidingFactory) GetValue(SourceProvidingFactoryProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProvidingFactoryProperty, value); }
    }


    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        SiblingComboBox.SelectionChanged += SiblingComboBoxOnSelectionChanged;
        SiblingComboBox.Loaded += SiblingComboBoxOnLoaded;
    }

    private void SiblingComboBoxOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        AssociatedObject.ItemsSource = null;
        var siblingCombo = sender as ComboBox;
        InitAssociatedObjectItemsSource(siblingCombo);
    }


    private void SiblingComboBoxOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        AssociatedObject.ItemsSource = null;
        var siblingCombo = sender as ComboBox;
        InitAssociatedObjectItemsSource(siblingCombo);
    }

    private void InitAssociatedObjectItemsSource(ComboBox siblingCombo)
    {
        if (siblingCombo == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (SourceProvidingFactory == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        AssociatedObject.ItemsSource = SourceProvidingFactory.GetCollection(siblingCombo.SelectedItem);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        SiblingComboBox.SelectionChanged -= SiblingComboBoxOnSelectionChanged;
        SiblingComboBox.Loaded -= SiblingComboBoxOnLoaded;
    }
}
```

This is a complete solution just copy/past...
I'll be glad to help if you will have any problems with the code.

Regards.

Comment: i dont want it to be MVVM

Comment: @DasDas please check out the new solution, it is based on the wpf behavior and code behind approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a very basic problem we face in such scenario. now as you don't have problem with display and binding I'll just write down what I think the problem is.

Don't use **active_idnt_deviceCmb.ItemsSource** this will reset all the Combobox Item Source. You want different option in different rows based on the other column value. **So you need to maintain one to one relationship for each record to each dropdown.**

The best way to do so is what ever class is binded to per record you need to create that many data sources. if `List<MyRecord>` is itemsource of grid then design the class like:

```
public class MyRecord : INotifyPropertyChanged
{      
    private string a;
    public string A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("A");
        OnPropertyChanged("SecondList");
        }
    }

    private string b;
    public string B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("B");
        }
    }

    private List<ComboBoxItem> firstList;
    public List<ComboBoxItem> FirstList
    {
        get { return firstList; }
        set { firstList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstList");
        }
    }

    private List<ComboBoxItem> secondList;
    public List<ComboBoxItem> SecondList
    {
        get { return secondList.Where(x=>x.value.StartsWith(A)).ToList(); }
        set { secondList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SecondList");
        }
    }


}
```

**PS:** First column of grid is bind with A, second with B, and firstlist and secondlist is bind to dropdown of both columns. every time I select the value in first column it will reflected back to property A and at that point I'm refreshing the secondlist(which also contain filter logic also, or you can call filter logic and refresh secondlist separately).

**As this second list is bind with only one record only one dropdown will reset.**

XAML Code for understanding:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="active_idnt_deviceCmb"
                                    SelectedValuePath="value"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="display"                                         
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding A}"                                        
                                    Header="input id" Width="80">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=FirstList}" />   
                    </Style>
                   </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn  
                                    SelectedValuePath="value"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="display"                                        
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding B}"
                                    Header="Relay Address" Width="65">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=SecondList}" />                                  
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Combobox item source class(just to understand DataGridComboBoxColumn binding):

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public ComboBoxItem(string a)
    {
        display = value = a;
    }

    public string display { get; set; }

    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

hopefully You'll be able to fit this code in your application. The main thing is One to One relationship that is important.